# Google Sheets: Splitting siblings by different @class attributes into columns using IMPORTXML formula

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

Good day, everyone! ^^

I am still a beginner in Google Sheets formulas and still don't understand many things, but I am trying to scrape sample sentences from an online Japanese dictionary using IMPORTXML in spreadsheet.

[image]

As shown on the image above, some `ul` descendants are categorized by 2 different `span @classes`, or has sibling, from some `li` parents.

`<span class="furigana">` ***

`<span class="unlinked">`

*** *[for those who don't know] **furigana**, in Japanese, is basically their assigned phonetic character as reading aid for their Kanji letters (characters borrowed or adapted from Chinese writing)*

And on the other hand, other `li` parents has 1 child only, and that is
`<span class="unlinked">`

> 

My goal is to split `@class='furigana'` and `@class='unlinked'` into 2 separate columns and those `'unlinked'` characters that doesn't have any `'furigana'` counterpart will be replaced with `—` symbol instead of a blank cell.

> 

I haven't done any filtering on my formula yet, but here it is:

`= IMPORTXML( "https://jisho.org/word/%E6%A4%85%E5%AD%90", "//span[@class='furigana']/ancestor::ul[@class='japanese japanese_gothic clearfix']/li[@class='clearfix']" )`

[image]

What happened was my formula miraculously gave me 2 columns for some reason that I don't understand, which is somewhat beneficial on my part, and seemingly already separated some `'unlinked'` characters from the `'furigana'` column. But I think it only segregated the characters in zigzag order, that's why some `'unlinked'` characters are on the `'furigana'` side.

I hope someone could help me and provide some simple formula that I could easily comprehend. My English is not that good as well so please bear with me. And from the bottom of my heart, THANK YOU SO MUCH in advance! Y_Y

Have a blessed day, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the array returned by your search.

The `<li>` items are being returned as rows, and each `<span>` within the `<li>` represents a column in said row.  Which value is returned in column 1 vs column 2 is dictated by the order of the spans in the HTML code, not the class name.  If there is only one `<span>` in an `<li>` it will be in column 1 regardless of the class name.

If you want to return only the `<span class='furigana'>` your formula would be

```
=IMPORTXML( 
  "https://jisho.org/word/%E6%A4%85%E5%AD%90",
  "//ul[@class='japanese japanese_gothic clearfix']/
    li[@class='clearfix']/span[@class='furigana']" 
 )
```

[image]

```
<ul class="japanese japanese_gothic clearfix" lang="ja">

  <li class="clearfix">
    <span class="furigana">かれ</span>
    <span class="unlinked">彼</span>
  </li>
  
  <li class="clearfix">
    <span class="unlinked">は</span>
  </li>

  <li class="clearfix">
    <span class="furigana">かなら</span>
    <span class="unlinked">必ず</span>
  </li>

  <li class="clearfix">
    <span class="furigana">だいとうりょう</span>
    <span class="unlinked">大統領</span>
  </li>
  
  <li class="clearfix">
    <span class="unlinked">の</span>
  </li>
   
  <li class="clearfix">
    <span class="furigana">いす</span>
    <span class="unlinked"><span class="hit">椅子</span></span>
  </li>

  <li class="clearfix">
    <span class="unlinked">に</span>
  </li>

  <li class="clearfix">
    <span class="unlinked">つく</span>
  </li>

  <li class="clearfix">
    <span class="furigana">じんぶつ</span>
    <span class="unlinked">人物</span>
  </li>
  
  <li class="clearfix">
    <span class="unlinked">だ</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```